# Alice Data Fixtures Errors on Windows

Tags: git, symfony, nelmio-alice

On my Windows when I pull/clone this project from git and run this command

```
 bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

Careful, database will be purged. Do you want to continue y/N ?y

> purging database  > loading AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\RequestFixture\RequestFixture
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>     Notice: Undefined offset: -5

It gives me an error.

But when I do it in my Mac, everything runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same problem on Windows using XAMPP, PHP 7.2.0, and Symfony 4.  The error that I had pointed me to `vendor\fzaninotto\faker\src\Faker\Provider\Base.php`.  Inside `Base::randomElements` there is the following statement:

```
$num = mt_rand(0, $highKey);
```

It looks like `$num` is then used to select a random item from the array of fake data that is passed in to `Base::randomElements` and then add it to the array of returned `$elements`.

The call to `mt_rand` is, in your case, returning `-5`.  The offset `-5` is not defined on the array which is expecting a positive number as the offset.

What I was able to figure out is that `mt_rand(0, $highKey)` is actually returning a number between `-$highKey/2` and `+$highKey/2`.  Furthermore, every time the method is invoked it always generates the exact same numbers.

I haven't been able to figure our why `mt_rand(0, $highKey)` produces a negative number.  It could be that the generator is improperly seeded, or it could be a bug in the implementation of `mt_rand`, but those just wild guesses at this point.